# Entity framework act as versioned equivalent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, entity-framework

Ruby on rails has this plugin where each table row change is copied to historic table before new attributes are set (see for instance https://github.com/laserlemon/vestal_versions). Is there anything like this for entity framework ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe so, but most sensible implementations of that functionality would use a Trigger on a table, writing changes into a separate Auditing table.